# LDAP integrated ELK shield plugin

Tags: linux, devops, elastic-stack

We are configuring ELK Shield plugin. 
The ELK server is integrated with LDAP server which is working fine. 
between ELK nodes.

The problem we are facing is with the configuration of Shield plugin. 
We have followed the official documentation but our Kibana dashboard is not coming up and giving error 502. We have checked almost all the logs which did not help.
For Kibana,  we have used Apache reverse proxy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option that I've done for this exact setup is to just have Apache do the LDAP auth:

```
<Directory /store/data/www>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName Restricted
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://<IP>:389/OU=XXX,OU=XXXX,DC=XX,DC=XXX?XXXXX"
  AuthLDAPBindDN CN=BIND_USER,CN=Users,DC=XX,DC=XXX
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <PASSWORD>
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```